# How to model fixed width columns for 2d bin/strip packing problem?

Tags: optimization, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming, glpk, bin-packing

I want to create a mathematical model for 2d bin packing optimization problem. I am not quite sure if it is bin packing problem it may be called strip packing, anyway let me introduce the problem.

1- There are some group of boxes to be placed on strips (see article 3.)

2- Each group contains a number of boxes which have same width and same hight. For example,

group A
100 boxes with width = 80cm and height = 120cm

group B
250 boxes with width = 150cm and height = 200cm

etc.

3- There are unlimited number of equal sized strips which have fixed width and height, for example

infinite number of Width = 800cm and Height 1400cm

4- The main goal is packing these boxes into minimum number of the strips. However, there are some restrictions to do this job.

**5- If we think of the strips as a 2d row and column plane, at each column must has a fixed width of boxes. For example, if (column 0 and row 0) has a box w=100,h=80 then (column 0 and row 1) also has to has a box w=100,h=80. It is not allowed to be in the same column for diferent sized boxes. This rule is not valid for rows. Each row can have different sized boxes, there is no restriction.**

**6- It is not important to fill the whole strip. We want to fill strips with minimum space between boxes. The heighest column indicates a stop line through other columns and we calculate the loss value (space ratio over the whole strip area).**

I tried to implement this optimization problem with GLPK linear programming tool. I have used a mathematical model from the paper (C. Blum, V. Schmid Solving the 2D bin packing problem by means of a hybrid evolutionary algorithm)
[C. Blum, V. Schmid Solving the 2D bin packing problem by means of a hybrid evolutionary algorithm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBtCG.png)

This math model works great in the GLPK. However, **it is designed for boxes for packing in x,y coordinates. If you see article 5 we want them in a fixed-width column fashion.**

Can you please help me to modify the mathematical model to make possible to implement article 5.
Thank you all,

Comment: Looks to me actually a simpler problem. No no-overlap constraints are needed. In the x and y-direction just keep track how many can fit. Probably a binary variable for the x-direction and a corresponding integer variable for the y-direction.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I unterstand that (2, 3, 4, 6 and 7 constraits from the original paper) might be removed from the model. May you please give me a clue about x (bin) and y (int) variables suggestion? I am quite newbie for linear-programming methods although I am a software engineer.

Comment: I was thinking about this a bit. There are also some other formulations one could explore. There may be more structure we can exploit.

Comment: Here are two different formulations: https://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2021/02/an-easy-variant-of-2d-bin-packing.html

Comment: Thank you for your well detailed formulations. I am going to implement your math model in Pulp (GLPK) as soon as possible and inform you about the results. I think article 6 is not included in your model, but I believe that I can add them in to the formulation (may be another penalty system) according to the great explanations from your blog post.

Comment: Indeed, I completely ignored point (6).